# help with jquery selector ul with levels

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have this html

```
<ul id="menu">
    <li><input type="button" id="btnMenu-1" class="btnMenu" value="pitillo"></li>
        <ul class="subMenu">
            <li><input type="button" id="SubBtn-1" class="btnSubMenu" value="sub-pitillo"></li>
    </ul>
    <li><input type="button" id="btnMenu-2" class="btnMenu" value="tal"></li>
        <ul class="subMenu">
            <li><input type="button" id="subBtn-2" class="btnSubMenu" value="sub-tal"></li>
        </ul>
</ul>
```

I want to select the sub menu but **not by the class**, in the moment when the user is **in mouse enter event** i tried like this but it doesn't work

$(document).ready(initialize);

```
function initialize(){
    $(".btnMenu").button();
    $("#menu li").hover(mouseEntry,mouseOut);
    $('.btnSubMenu').button();
}

function mouseEntry(){
    $('ul', this).slideDown(100);
 }

function mouseOut(){
    $('ul',this).slideUp(100);
}
```

[this is my live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9vLDy/27/)

Comment: What do you mean "it doesn't work"?

Comment: You probably should look into event bubbling in javascript, you would need to intercept the mouseover event fired by the subMenu. However why not dynamically add a class on mouseover and remove it on mouseout?

Comment: doesn't make the effect that i want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what you're after but changing the HTML to:

```
<ul id="menu">
    <li><input type="button" id="btnMenu-1" class="btnMenu" value="pitillo">
        <ul class="subMenu">
            <li><input type="button" id="SubBtn-1" class="btnSubMenu" value="sub-pitillo"></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><input type="button" id="btnMenu-2" class="btnMenu" value="tal">
        <ul class="subMenu">
            <li><input type="button" id="subBtn-2" class="btnSubMenu" value="sub-tal"></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

will put the subMenu into the menu so that your JavaScript actually slides it out.
You'll also have to make sure you select only the 'outer' li. This is done by adding a '>' to the selector:

```
function initialize(){
    $(".btnMenu").button();
    $("#menu>li").hover(mouseEntry,mouseOut);
    $('.btnSubMenu').button();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `<ul>` is not a child of the `<li>`, it's a sibling.  So use `.next()`.

http://jsfiddle.net/9vLDy/28/

```
function mouseEntry(){
    $(this).next('ul').slideDown(100);
}

function mouseOut(){
    $(this).next('ul').slideUp(100);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure if this is what you're going for, but try changing your mouseEntry / mouseOut events to:

```
$("ul", $(this))
```

Comment: `this` is fine. jQuery expects a DOM element as context.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function initialize(){
    $(".btnMenu").button();
    $("#menu > li").hover(mouseEntry,mouseOut);
    $('.btnSubMenu').button();
}

function mouseEntry(){
    $(this).find('>ul').slideDown(100);
 }

function mouseOut(){
    $(this).find('>ul').slideUp(100);
}
```